# NbClust nstart and iter.max options

Tags: r, classification, k-means, goodness-of-fit

I am interested in using the NbClust package to try and evaluate various classification solutions. I know that NbClust has methods to implement such algorithms but these are limited. In particular NBClust does not allow multiple starts or an increase in the maximum number of iterations (nstart and iter.max in kmeans). NbClust is warning me that the maximum number of iterations has been exceeded, but no way of increasing it. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to apply these two options in NbClust? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Copy source code of NBclust and edit max iterations in there:
https://rdrr.io/cran/NbClust/src/R/NbClust.R